# ffmpeg dont work in php shell_exec("ffmpeg -i $movie $pic &")

Tags: php, ffmpeg

I'm running the following script without any problems:

```
<?php
echo $video  = dirname(__FILE__)."\\MOVIES\\1.mp4";
echo "<br>";
echo $pic  = dirname(__FILE__)."\\PICTURES\\1.jpg";
echo shell_exec("ffmpeg -i  $video  $pic &");
```

But when I run this one i get nothing:

```
echo shell_exec("ffmpeg -i  C:\xampp\htdocs\Video-share-script\MOVIES\1.mp4  C:\xampp\htdocs\Video-share-script\PICTURES\1.jpg &");
```

the value of $video is C:\xampp\htdocs\Video-share-script\MOVIES\1.mp4
and $pic is C:\xampp\htdocs\Video-share-script\PICTURES\1.jpg
thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using double quotes `"`, but not escaping your backslashes `\` with another backslash.

Swap out `\` for `\\` in the path and try it.

Also, be aware of the security implications here.  Use [`escapeshellarg()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.escapeshellarg.php), otherwise some paths may get interpreted as commands.

Comment: thanks Brad but i have problem with second code. the question is why when i use variable program works but when i use value it dos'nt work

Comment: @josef Not sure what you're asking... your second bit of code isn't properly using backslashes.